# Time complexity of the code below?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

Can someone tell me the time complexity for the following code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char a[100]= "Gosh I am confused :D";
int i,count= -1,display_ToVal= strlen(a)-1, display_FromVal;

for( i=strlen(a)-1 ; i>=0 ; i=i+count)
{
        if ( (a[i] == ' ' || i == 0) && count == -1)
        {
         cout << " ";
         display_FromVal = i;
         count = 1;
         if ( i == 0 )
                cout << a[i];
         continue;
        }       

        else if( count == 1 && i == display_ToVal)
        {
         cout << a[i];
         display_ToVal = display_FromVal - 1;
         i = display_FromVal;
         count = -1;
         if(display_FromVal == 0)
                 break;
         else
                 continue;
        }

        else if (count == 1)
         cout << a[i];

        else
         continue;
}

return 1;
}
```

I am really confused as to whether this can be classified as *O(n)*.  Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: If you tell us what makes you doubt it is O(N), we can help you understand better.

Comment: Nitpick: What is n, your input size? As written, the code does not take any input and runs in constant time. “Duh, the string length” is not really a complete answer, since it looks like the behavior depends on spaces in the string, which is yet another parameter of the input.

Comment: @Cristopher: Complexity would depend on the size of the string anyway.
I think the correct question here is what is the best, average and worst case time complexity here.

Comment: I have just hardcoded the i/p in this scenario, but i/p could be anything. Since the value of I increments and decrements, I was in a dilemma as to whether this can be considered as O(n).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The algorithm can be summarrized in pseudo-code as :

1. mark the current position
2. go backward one character at a time until a space is found or end of input is reached
3. now go forward copying each character to output, then go back to 1., except if eoi is reached

So the input is traversed once in reverse, and one more time forward, but without coming back to a previously read position in either step 2. or 3. And when switching from step 3. to 1. it directly adjust the iterator. The `count` variable is used to track the state of the algorithm (it is in fact a simple state-machine). It is also reused to define the direction of the iteration.

So, the algorithm is in fact `O(n)`.

---

For more clarity, it could be rewritten as this, without changing the complexity:

```
void printStringWithWordReversed(const char* a) {
    int i,j,display_ToVal= strlen(a)-1, display_FromVal;
    for( i=display_ToVal; i>=0 ; i=i+-1)
    {
        if ( (a[i] == ' ' || i == 0))
        {
         // When entering this branch, we are switching from state 2 to
         // state 3 (this is the content of the first branch).
         cout << " ";
         display_FromVal = i;
         if ( i == 0 )
                cout << a[i];
         // This loop correspond to the state 3, and is equivalent to the
         // previous code in the particular case when count == 1.
         for (j = display_FromVal+1; j <= display_ToVal; j=j+1)
         {
             cout << a[j];
         }
         // This postlude correspond to the transition from state 3 to state 1
         // and correspond to the second branch in the original algorithm.
         display_ToVal = display_FromVal - 1;
         if ( i == 0 )
            break;
         continue;
        }       
    }
}
```

So we lookup each word starting from the end and output them in correct order. This is clearly `O(n)` with both implementation (both in time and space if we assume that `cout` insertion operator for `char` is `O(1)`) since adding a *fixed number* (here two) of `O(n)` algorithm is still `O(n)` (the constant is ignored).

Comment: first solution that notices i doesn't change by a constant value. +1

Comment: First solution that *explains* and doesn't jump into the "one loop = O(N)" fallacy. +1

Comment: Thanks, answer to the point. I was confused as to whether this scenario of the looping variable incrementing as well decrementing while traversing throught the input can be termed as O(n). Your explanation helped. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -2):

"{for( i=strlen(a)-1 ; i>=0 ; i=i+count)}"

There is only one for loop in your code and its index i is varying linearly .
Thats why its O(n)

Comment: The "one loop = O(N)" fallacy. `i` does no vary linearly.

Comment: int i =1;int n=1000; while(i < = n)i*=2; complexity O(lgN) because here index of while loop in not varying linearly .I said the same thing for above code and i didn't get the reason of -1 :(

Comment: `i` varies up and down, because count can be either +1 or -1. I downvoted because the explanation of linear behavior is very poor (inexistent). A useful answer would help clear the confusion of the OP.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice that i could be -1.BTW my explanation does not seem to be vague :)

Comment: Technically speaking, this answer is probably correct. Even logN is O(N). Of course, it is entirely possible for a single loop to be Omega(nlg n) even. Even with i=i+count.