# Reverse the orders of words--time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, string

Input: "My Name is Pritam"
Output: "Pritam is Name My"

I have written this so far, but I'm bit confused with time complexity

```
public string ReverseWordsInAString(string str)
    {
        char[] temp = str.ToCharArray();
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = str.Length - 1;
        temp = ReverseString(temp, startIndex, endIndex);
        endIndex = 0;
        foreach (char c in temp)
        {
            if(c == ' ')
            {
                temp = ReverseString(temp, startIndex, endIndex-1);
                startIndex = endIndex + 1;
            }
            if (endIndex == str.Length-1)
            {
                temp = ReverseString(temp, startIndex, endIndex);
            }
            endIndex++;
        }
        str = new string(temp);
        return str;
    }

    public char[] ReverseString(char[] chr, int start, int end)
    {
        while (start < end)
        {
            char temp = chr[start];
            chr[start] = chr[end];
            chr[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        return chr;
    }
```

When I call ReverseString method from a for loop I think it no more a O(n) solution. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Does anyone have any better solution.

Comment: I see the updated title.  I suppose my answer is not much use.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know whether my code is O(n) complexity or not. I'm bit confused with the for loop. And if it is not O(n) then if anyone have any better solution that will really help me. But thanks  for posting.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a naive or foolish question, but is it unreasonable to simply test your code on different data sets an plot the result?  Or, are you in need of a rigorous proof of complexity?  By the way, you may want to tag this question for a specific language, it attracted several answers (mine included) as though it were a "Rosetta Stone" question.

Comment: I'm calling ReverseString method from a for loop. for loop definitely O(n) operatrions, but that ReverseString processing every word inside that string. So I'm not sure whether it is a O(n*(all words length)/2) operation or O(n+ (all words length)/2) operation. Please forgive me if it is too much silly question.

Answer (score 2):

in Java

```
String str= "My Name is Pritam";
String arr[] = str.split(" ");
for(int i = arr.length-1 ; i >=0 ; i--){
   System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: length-1, otherwise you'll get an index out of bounds

Answer (score 2):

Your code is `O(n)`. You can see this by looking at the number of swaps each element is involved in, which is *2* (once for the initial reverse of the entire string, second for the word-wise reversal). In addition the `foreach` loop iterates over each element exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby:

```
sentence = "My name is Pritam"
print sentence.split(" ").reverse.join(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In C;

```
char *s = "My Name is Pritam", *t = s + strlen(s), *end = strchr(s,' ')-1;
while( t != end )
{
  *(t = strrchr(t,' ')) = '\0';
  printf( "%s ", --t+2 );
}
printf( "%s", s );
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate, I had asked a similar question some time back. But the responses I received were very interesting, actually it did change the way complexity should be thought about ;).... [Time Complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704411/time-complexity-of-the-code-below)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and push it to a stack .  Pop elements from stack and add it to  a new string. Requires extra space,but just posted because it could be a easy way to implement string reverse

```
public class StringReverse {

public static void main (String args[]){

    String input = "My name is Pritam";

    Stack<String> stack  = new Stack<String>();

    String[] strings= input.split(" ");

    for(String str :strings){
        stack.push(str);
    }

    String reverse = "" ;

    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        reverse = reverse + " " + stack.pop();
    }

    System.out.println(reverse);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in Python,

```
sentence = "My name is Pritam"
' '.join(sentence.split(" ")[::-1])
```